# Buscar valor de variável

Tags: php, javascript

Pessoal eu tenho um form para cadastro de candidato. Para salvar no banco ele passa os valores pelo javascript para o **salvaCandidato.php**. To tentando fazer com que ao enviar o form apareça o modal dizendo o protocolo da inscrição que ta na variável **$nr_prot** em **salvaCandidato.php**, não estou conseguindo.

**index.php**

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Observação</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Anote seu protocolo</h4>
        <h4>$nr_prot</h4>
        <h4> O protocolo foi enviado para o email </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**salvaCandidato.php**

```html
  $sqlProt = "SELECT * FROM candidato WHERE cpf_cand = '$_POST[cpf_cand]'";
  $queryProt = mysqli_query($conexao,$sqlProt);
  $fetchProtocolo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryProt);
  $nr_prot =  $fetchProtocolo['nr_prot'];
```

Comment: Você não pode por uma variável do PHP dentro do HTML puro como fez `<h4>$nr_prot</h4>`. Se o modal abre pelo PHP você precisa usar `<h4><?php echo $nr_prot;?></h4>`

Comment: Era só pra ilustrar, tentei usar $_SESSION e $_POST, mas não vem

Comment: Você vai ter que colocar o número do protocolo no modal via javascript.
Veja um exemplo $("#modal-body").html('seu numero de protocolo');

Answer (score 0):

Pode-se fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
  $variavelphp = "<script>document.write(variaveljs)</script>";
  echo "$variavelphp";
?>
```

Você vai editar apenas o **variaveljs** e colocar a sua variavel!

.

Não sei se conseguir te ajudar, mas espero que sim!

Comment: No caso, como vai ficar o varivaljs, não consegui testar, desde já agradeço

Comment: Do seu codigo html <script>var variaveljs = "Sua var";</script> , usar o codigo acima para pegar da variavel js para o php, e para imprimir o que dejesa, usa: <h4><?php echo $nr_prot; ?><h4>, do jeito que apresentaram no comentario alí em cima!